# iOS in-app purchase for a paid app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I created an app which is a paid app. Now I want to make it free so more user can download the app and use in app purchase to limit some features. But some user already paid to buy my app. How can I implement in app purchase for new user at the same time keep full feature access to old user?

Comment: Please add a new tag whether it's for Android or iOS. Anyone might be confused.

Comment: Thanks everyone. fortunately I just launch my app for a few weeks. There are not much user yet. So, I think I will just make the in-app-purchase free for a while and make the current user to buy it for free. and change the price on next version update. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect to your server for registering user info, you can always create an API which executes on app launch to verify that user is full access user or not.

But I am afraid your case is not the above one.

In that case you would require to sync your data (some encrypted key in this context) with iCloud and when application is launched you can verify the type of user.

Using data in iCloud is more safer as compared to keychain as it covers device format scenario. But definitely not foolproof.

Other solution can be using Apple Purchase Receipt to verify the version of previous purchase. But this is only supported since iOS7.

Checkout some opensource libs to understand the parsing of receipts:
https://github.com/rmaddy/VerifyStoreReceiptiOS

So combining multiple strategies is the only answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by reading the [App Store receipt](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html). The receipt contains the version number and date of the original purchase.

There are two main caveats: first, this only works on iOS 7 and above. Secondly, Apple don't include code for parsing the receipt (so it's not too easy for users to hack I understand). There are, however, onen source libraries, though using a common one will be less secure.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example, but if you're working with a database on a server (not on the phone itself), can't you use a boolean for each feature you plan on selling, and just set that boolean to true for all users currently in the database.  This is assuming true means they've bought the feature, and false means they haven't bought it. 
You could run this query once after releasing your updated app, and then every user after that would have a default value of false for these features you're selling.

Comment: thanks @kacy, this is a quick solution. However if the user deleted the app and reinstall it later. I somehow need to provide a way for them to restore the purchase, right? this is the part that I have no idea how to do. Sorry By the way, I am talking about iOS. Thanks

Comment: @CkwCfm If a user deletes the app, you would still have this information stored for the user in your database.  When the user reinstalls the app, you could use the information stored in your database.

Comment: The confusion might be because I don't think it's clear from your answer that you mean a database on a server rather than something in the iPhone app.

Comment: @StephenDarlington Oh I didn't even consider a database on the phone.  Yeah I meant on a server.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

There are no perfect solutions to this scenario.

Suggestion 1:

Roll out one last paid update.  In this update, use keychain to store those IAP flags.  Then in the free version, check for these flags in keychain.  This will work even if app was deleted and reinstalled with the free version later.  But it will not work if the device is being reset completely whether due to some iOS version updates or user's unless a backup and restore also is involved.

Suggestion 2:

Not quite a suggestion.  But I have seen similar apps on AppStore have just rollout free version.  Then app incurred bad reviews from those previous users!